# Algorithm for creating a "relative" priority queue? (c/c++)

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, list, queue

I want to make a queue using linked lists.
There are numerous algorithms out there for that. But what i'm curious in is how to make a relative priority queue.

Maybe there is a special name for this type of queue, but i don't know it, and i haven't had any luck googling for the solution.

Anyways, let's say i have this struct, which will represent the Node of my list.

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node* next;
}
```

if i want to create a priority queue (where the element with the least value is first), when i insert for example 5 7 1 8 2, my list should look like this:

```
1 -> 2 -> 5 -> 7 -> 8
```

It's not really hard to implement that.
What i want to do is - when i insert the first element, other elements should have value relative to the previous element. So, in my example, the list/queue would contain the following values:

```
1 -> 1 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1
```

I'm not really sure how i would implement that? Would the following idea be applicable:

in the Node struct i add another field, which would represent the original value.
i find the position of the node i'm inserting the same way i would do when creating an ordinary linked list, and then i just say

```
temp->value = temp->originalValue - previous->originalValue;
```

Comment: Your proposed solution seems pretty reasonable.

Comment: @NateKohl his proposed solution is broken - he needs to modify both the "previous" and the "next" node for it to work, and it's just... ugly. Why is this sort of data structure needed?

Comment: @NikBougalis: Ah, right.

Comment: @NikBougalis: I guess it could be used to represent a long sequence of increasing numbers compactly (like primes).

Comment: @jxh compactly is relative... I think this is just a case where a poorly conceived square peg is being hammered into a round hole.

Comment: @NikBougalis Yes, i'm aware that i need to modify next and previous pointers. I just tried to emphasize the difference between a "regular" priority queue, and this type.

The reason i need this is because i'm implementing a Thread interface in c++, as a part of my University project.
I need to be able to put a thread to sleep, and when i wake a thread up, it would be somewhere less work, because i would'nt iterate through the list decrementing each value, i would just do that while the decremented values are == 0. I hope i managed to explain it correctly :)

Comment: @Nicholas I'm not sure I follow, no.

Comment: @Nicholas - like what this http://playtechs.blogspot.com/2008/06/relative-priority-queue.html describes, right?

Comment: I'm not really following either. What does this data structure buy you instead of just using a regular run-of-the-mill priority queue?

Comment: @NikBougalis When i put a thread to sleep, i give it a certain time (value in my example), which represents the time thread needs to sleep.

When a system/processor clock ticks, i call a function that iterates through a priority queue, decrements the time of each thread, and if that time has become 0, it wakes the thread (removes it from the list). This way, i have to iterate through the whole list, so i decrement the time of each element.

With relative queue, i just decrement time of the first element, and if it's 0 i wake it up (remove from the list), and stop iterating.

Comment: @Nicholas: Google for *timer wheel*. It solves this problem. Generally, though, your timing structure should use absolute time values for expiration. Then, you just check for timers that have expiration values less than the current time. Then, the only other issue is to use a monotonic clock for your times.

Comment: @greatwolf It buys me time, it's faster. If a system clock ticks every 55ms, i don't always iterate through the whole list, just those elements that have value that will become 0 after decrementing. That is usually the first element.

and thanks for suggesting timer wheel, i'll look that up ;)

Comment: @Nicholas a timer wheel, as jxh suggested, is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store extra data in each node, either the relative priority, or a "previous" pointer. Since the next node's relative priority needs to updated whenever a node is removed (how to do that without a prev pointer?), I suggest the "previous" pointer:

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
}
```

Then a function can evaluate the relative priority:

```
int relative_priority(Node* node) {
    if (node == NULL)
        return 0;
    if (node->prev == NULL)
        return node->value;
    return node->value - node->prev->value;
}
```

Note that I'm using C, you'll need to replace NULL with 0 for C++

Answer (score 0):

You first have to identify where to insert the new node. This involves decrements on the target value, adjusting its relative value in relation to the current in the list. At the point of insertion, you have to point the previous node to the new node, and then adjust the node ahead of the new node with a new relative value.

```
Node * create_node (int value, Node *next) { /* ... */ }

void insert_relative_priority_queue (Node **head, int value) {
    Node **prev = head, *cur;
    if (*head) {
        cur = *head;
        while (value > cur->value) {
            value -= cur->value;
            prev = &cur->next;
            cur = cur->next;
            if (cur == 0) break;
        }
        *prev = create_node(value, cur);
        if (cur) {
            cur->value -= value;
        }
    } else {
        *head = create_node(value, 0);
    }
}
```

When you remove from the front of the list, you adjust the value of the new `head`:

```
void remove_relative_priority_queue (Node **head) {
    if (*head) {
        Node *cur = *head;
        *head = cur->next;
        if (*head) {
            (*head)->value += cur->value;
        }
        free(cur);
    }
}
```